# How to work with multiple files in the Nice Editor text editor

Tags: text-editors

When using the [Nice Editor](http://ne.di.unimi.it/docs/index.html), how do you open multiple files, and then switch between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Opening Files

Hitting `Ctrl-O` will open a file browser, so you can select a file to edit. The selected file will replace the current document, so there will still be the same number of open documents.

Using `Esc-N` works the same as `Ctrl-O`, except that the selected file is added to the list of currently open files. This allows you to have multiple files open.

Personally, I prefer a much more conventional set up, where `Ctrl-O` does what `Esc-N` does (and `Esc-N` then does nothing). It is easy to make `ne` work that way by adding the following line to your *keys file* (see appendix):

```
KEY 0f OpenNew
```

Files are always rendered fullscreen, so you can only see one file at any point in time.

### Switching Between Open Files

There are [`NextDoc`](http://ne.di.unimi.it/docs/Key-Bindings.html) and [`PrevDoc`](http://ne.di.unimi.it/docs/PrevDoc.html#PrevDoc) commands for cycling through a carousel of your open documents. There is also a [`SelectDoc`](http://ne.di.unimi.it/docs/SelectDoc.html#SelectDoc) command that opens a navigable list of open documents to select from.

The `NextDoc`, `PrevDoc` and `SelectDoc` commands are aliased to `ND`, `PD` and `SD` respectively.

You can enter `ne` commands at the prompt, or bind shortcuts to them (see appendix).

### Appendix: Custom Keybindings

You can configure keybindings in `ne` by creating and editing a file that lives at `~/.ne/.keys`. See [the Keybinding docs](http://ne.di.unimi.it/docs/Key-Bindings.html) for more information.